# Transform screenshots to look like a photograph

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transform

I want to give my screenshots a 3d, realistic photograph effect.

Something like this:

[image]

I tried using Skew but it didn't bring me desired result. Can anyone help me through?

Comment: Are you having trouble with the shape, the texture, the lighting? There's quite a bit at work in the screenshot you posted; where are you stuck?

Comment: I have created a pixelated texture which brings the screen effect but my main problem lies in transforming the image into that realistic perpective.

I did try to achieve achieve the effect using skew but the image didn't look as realistic.

Comment: Anyone getting here through Google might have more success looking at the answers to [another question (and the one linked on that question)](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13989/how-can-i-make-a-screenshot-look-like-a-photograph-taken-of-a-real-surface) in case this question didn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the vanishing point filter. Check out this 
[Vanishing Point Tutorial](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tutorials-effects/using-the-vanishing-point-filter-to-mock-up-a-business-card/)

maybe it will give you a general idea of how you need to implement it for your project.